# Microsoft Graph - Searching OneDrive

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Based on the [Microsoft Graph REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), we have Xamarin/C# code that looks something like this:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
   new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
      (requestMessage) =>
         {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
            return (Task.FromResult(0));
         }
      ));
IDriveItemSearchCollectionPage search = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
   .Search("{search-query}")
   .Request()
   .GetAsync();
```

The problem is, I can't find any documentation about what "{search-query}" can be.  By trial and error, it appears that:

1. Searching for "A" finds all files that contain an "A" in their name or contents
2. Searching for "{search-query}" returns a couple of files, I have no idea why
3. Searching for "filename:A" returns nothing even though I have a few files that contain "A" in their name

I want to search for all files whose name contains a certain substring, but if I search for "*" or "filename:A*" or "filename:A%2A" it throws a ServiceException with the code UnknownError.

**Question 1**: How do I pass a wildcard to the Search() function?

Then, when I do get results, it's a `Microsoft.Graph.DriveItemSearchCollectionPage`, I can enumerate through that and get a bunch of `DriveItem` objects.  `DriveItem` has a property named "Folder" that is sometimes **non-null**, but it's an object of type `Microsoft.Graph.Folder` and Intellisense indicates there is no way to get the name of the folder.  And the current version of Visual Studio Mac is screwy, if I right-click on a folder and select "Go To Declaration" it immediately hangs and uses 100% CPU and never returns, I have to Force Quit.

**Question 2**: How do I get the name of a folder when I have a `Microsoft.Graph.Folder`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Drive search query syntax.

I can say that when the Folder property is non-null, it indicates that the DriveItem is a folder. You'll use DriveItem.Name to get the name of the folder.